# Getting the Change Event from a Checkbox in a grid using WPF/MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I have a dataset that is essentially a list of objects with a boolean property in them that is bound to a DataGrid (DXGrid to be specific). I am trying to get the IsChecked property to populate on the clicking of the checkbox.  In the case of a standalone textbox, i would use the UpdateSourceTrigger option of Binding, but in the DXGrid at least, that doesn't seem to be available.  As it is, I have to lose focus of the checkbox in order to update the property.

Any Ideas?

Assume that the RaisePropertyChanged function below is an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Data Object

```
public class MyObject
{
  bool _isChecked;
  string _name;
  int _id;

  public MyObject(OtherObject oo)
  {
       _name = oo.Name;
       _id = oo.ID;
  }

  public int ID
  { get { return _id; }}

  public string Name
  { get { return _name; }}

  public bool IsChecked
  {
      get { return _isChecked; }
      set
      {
          if (value == _isChecked)
              return;
          _isChecked = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
      }
  }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class MyTestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    #region Fields
    #endregion

    public MyTestViewModel(Message message)
        : base(message)
    {
        AvailableObjects = PopulateDataSet();
    }

    #region Properties
    public List<MyObject> AvailableObjects { get; set; }
}
```

view XAML

```
  <dxg:GridControl x:Name="SearchGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MaxHeight="1024" AutoPopulateColumns="True" DataSource="{Binding Path=AvailableObjects}" >
      <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
          <dxg:GridColumn Header="Select" Width="60" FixedWidth="True" FieldName="IsChecked" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True"></dxg:GridColumn>
          <dxg:GridColumn Header="ID Number" Width="130" FixedWidth="True" ReadOnly="True"  FieldName="ID"></dxg:GridColumn>
          <dxg:GridColumn Header="Name"  FieldName="Name" ReadOnly="True"></dxg:GridColumn>
      </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
      <dxg:GridControl.View>
          <dxg:TableView AllowEditing="True" x:Name="view" IndicatorWidth="0" AutoWidth="True"/>
      </dxg:GridControl.View>
  </dxg:GridControl>
```

Comment: If you were using WPF's built-in DataGrid with a DataGridCheckBoxColumn, you could just bind the column to your IsChecked property with `Mode=TwoWay`... But I'm afraid I couldn't tell you how to do that with a DXGrid.

Comment: I can add an unbound checkbox to the grid (I actually tried that before with mixed results).  Assuming i do what would the Binding Path be?  {Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay} didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
                    <dxg:GridColumn>
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <dxe:CheckEdit Checked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a special Checkbox (like a DXCheckbox or something) or just a normal WPF Checkbox.  In the case of the latter, the binding would be IsChecked={Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}.

Do you get any binding errors in your output window?